# Java calendar , set a task as recurring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Here is the code that I currently have which is being used to reschedule activities. It is working fine:D.
This will basically reschedule an activity 24 hours ahead of the current time.

I would like to have recurring activities (for example the option for the activity to be rescheduled every day) and if possible until a set date.

Does anyone have any advice?

```
@Override
public void rescheduleActivity(int id) {

    Activity activity = activityRepositoryJPA.findById(id);

    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
    Timestamp newDate = Timestamp.valueOf(date.plus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS));

    activity.setStartDateTime(newDate);
    activityRepositoryJPA.saveAndFlush(activity);

}
```

Comment: For an actual moment on the timeline, do *not* use `LocalDateTime` as that class lacks any notion of time zone or offset-from-UTC. You want `Instant` instead, a point on the timeline in UTC.

Comment: @KabiraSuleman Was your issue resolved ??? If yes, then upvote and accept correct answer from below else let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you are using Spring Boot. With Spring Boot, you can enable scheduling simply by adding the @EnableScheduling annotation to the main application class or any other configuration class.

You can schedule tasks using @Scheduled annotation. For examples;

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
 public void scheduleTaskWithFixedRate() {
   // ...
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
 public void scheduleTaskWithFixedDelay() {
   // ...
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000, initialDelay = 5000)
 public void scheduleTaskWithFixedRateAndInitialDelay() {
   // ...
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
  // ...
}
```

You have so much flexibility to schedule tasks periodically or repeatedly as per your needs.

Comment: thank you so much i didnt know about this annotation

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are trying to make this more generic. Then, better option would be adding another parameter as `Timestamp`, which has new `Timestamp` for your activity.

```
public void rescheduleActivity(int id, Timestamp newDate) {

    Activity activity = activityRepositoryJPA.findById(id);

    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

    activity.setStartDateTime(newDate);
    activityRepositoryJPA.saveAndFlush(activity);

}
```

Then, call it

```
Timestamp newDate = Timestamp.valueOf(date.plus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS));
rescheduleActivity (5,newDate);
```

Comment: so would that reschedule the activity five times (for five days)?

Comment: @KabiraSuleman I have helped you generalizing your method, Now, I don't know, what and how your method works. For now, you can call your method multiple times for multiple/same activity id and set different timestamp.